# How to trigger local reference in child component from parent component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

In scenario when I have

parent component:

```
  <button (click)="panel.toggle($event)">Click</div>
```

child:

```
   <child></child> which has the reference

     and includes

     <p-overlayPanel  #panel>
       Content
    </p-overlayPanel>
```

How can I access #panel reference from parent component? PrimeNG overlay panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @ViewChild(‘panel’) panel: ParentComponent
```

Using `@ViewChild()` decorator you can access child component from parent component

Comment: I have no idea about toggle. You can read official document of panel

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle: this.panel.show(); this.panel.hide();